# Why is db printing #object[Object [object Object]] in reframe?

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

In the following code I'm dispatching two on-click events:

```
;; event
(reg-event-db
 :some
 (fn [db [_ some-val]]
   (prn "The db is" db)
   (assoc db :some some-val)
   ))

;; another event
(reg-event-db
 :another
 (fn [db [_ another-val]]
   (prn "The db is" db)
   (assoc db :another another-val)
   ))

;; button
[:input {:type "button" :value "Button"
         :on-click #(do
                       (dispatch [:some :some-val])
                       (dispatch [:another :another-val]))}]
```

But instead of printing the db map, it prints `"The db is"  #object[Object [object Object]]`, and then

```
Error: No protocol method IAssociative.-assoc defined for type object: [object Object]
```

What am I doing wrong? I also tried doing `#(dispatch [:some :some-val :another another-val]` but that gave the same error. In general, how to correctly dispatch two events?

Answer (score 0):

This is correct:

```
(do
  (dispatch [:first-event :some-value])
  (dispatch [:second-event :other-value]))
```

This is **not** correct:

```
(dispatch [:some :some-val :another another-val])
```

In this example, you are dispatching one event with 3 arguments:

- `:some` is the event name,
- `:some-val` is the first argument,
- `:another` is the second argument,
- `another-val` is the 3rd argument.

The error you are encountering doesn't come from the way you `dispatch` events, but rather from your `db` state. Let's dissect it step by step:

If `(prn db)` outputs `#object[Object [object Object]]` it means `db` is a JavaScript object.

If `(assoc db …)` fails with `No protocol method IAssociative.-assoc defined for type object: [object Object]`, it means the `db` value does not support the `assoc` function. The `assoc` function is defined by a protocol (think interface) and this protocol is implemented on maps. So here, `db` is not a map.

**Why would `db` be a JavaScript object instead of a Clojure map?**

When you use `(reg-event-db :event-name handler-function)`, the value returned by `handler-function` will replace the `db` state. If by mistake you return a JS object, it will become the new `db` value, and this new incorrect `db` value will get passed to subsequent event handlers. So it's highly probable that **one of your event handlers is returning a JavaScript object.**

How I would solve this situation:

- use `(js/console.log db)` instead of `(prn db)`. You'll be able to see what's inside this js object. `prn` doesn't know how to print js objects properly.
- make sure [cljs-devtools](https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-devtools) is installed and running. It allows you to explore complex objects in the console. Next time this issue arises, you'll immediately see what's the problematic value instead of an opaque string representation.
- use `reg-event-fx` instead of `reg-event-db`. While a little bit more verbose, it will make more explicit to the human eye what value you are putting in `db`.
- if you want to go further and ensure this never happens again, take a look at [Re-Frame Middlewares](https://github.com/day8/re-frame/wiki/Using-Handler-Middleware). In your case, middlewares would allow you to act on handlers returned values, and potentially reject it if it doesn't match your expectations.